# interpretation of the conditional mean

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, descriptive-statistics

If i have 2 random vectors $X$ and $Y$, each of them with own different pdf, what is the conceptual interpretation of saying that the conditional expectation of $X$ given $Y$ is null? i.e.
\begin{equation}
E[X|Y] = 0
\end{equation}
Thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to see something like "$E[X|Y=y]=0$ for all $y$",  which could be taken as meaning that whatever the value of $Y$, the expected value of $X$ is $0$.

One example of this might be $Y$ having any distribution you want and $X$ taking the values $\pm Y$ with probability $\frac12$ each.  Since $|X|=|Y|$, they are not independent even though the value of $Y$ does not affect the expectation of $X$.

Comment: interesting... but i'm still having a doubt: why have you said $|X| = |Y|$ ? what's that identity's meaning?
Thank you very much!

Comment: In Henry's example X=Y or X=-Y so |X|=|Y|.

Comment: I probably should have required $Y$ to have a finite mean